# Problem with creating pdf file from html context in container with alpine linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, wkhtmltopdf

i have app with nodejs on backend and i am using wkhtmltopdf to create pdf from canvas. When i am running it on my pc via console (i have a windows) it will successfully create a pdf file and save it to my documents folder. However, when i deploy it on my test server the webservice is running in docker container with alpine linux 3.11 it want save the document to the fodler. The wkhtmltopdf is used from binary in repository(there is some problem with installing wkhtmltopdf on linux it wont work) and the binary is added to the bin folder in docker file. There is no runtime error in the code in logs.

```
pdf(content, { output: filePath, debug: true }, async function (e) {
              if (e) {
                req.log.error(e);
                req.log.info('[SIGN DOCUMENT] error creating pdf');
                return res.json(utils.errorJsonResponse(e.message));
              }
              req.log.info(
                '[User documents] Created PDF document: ' + filePath
              );
```

the pdf function si calling wkhtmltopdf(input, output, callback)

and my part of docker file for this

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    libgcc libstdc++ libx11 glib libxrender libxext libintl \
    libcrypto1.1 libssl1.1 \
    ttf-dejavu ttf-droid ttf-freefont ttf-liberation ttf-ubuntu-font-family \
    python make g++


# on alpine static compiled patched qt headless wkhtmltopdf (47.2 MB)
# compilation takes 4 hours on EC2 m1.large in 2016 thats why binary
COPY wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
RUN apk add --no-cache \
            xvfb \
            ttf-freefont \
            fontconfig \
            dbus \
    && \
    mv /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf-origin && \
    echo $'#!/usr/bin/env sh\n\
Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset & \n\
DISPLAY=:0.0 wkhtmltopdf-origin $@ \n\
killall Xvfb\
' > /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf && \
chmod +x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf-origin && \
chmod +x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

i tried to install wkhtmltopdf lib on linux but we have to use the binary file. I download different binary

Comment: You can install wkhtmltopdf on the server outside docker. Then call `wkhtmltopdf` command programmatically just like you would on the terminal